# Rails 5 belongs_to scoped validation

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-5.1

lets say I have this model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  enum post_type: { post: 0, page: 1 }

  belongs_to :user
end
```

by default rails 5 will make the `belongs_to :user` association to be required. And If you pass `optional: true` will make this association to be optional. But what I want is the `belongs_to :user` association to be optional only when the `post_type` is `page` and when it is `post` to required.

How can I do it at the line `belongs_to :user` ?

At this moment I am doing this:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  enum post_type: { post: 0, page: 1 }

   belongs_to :user, optional: true
   validates :user_id, presence: { scope: post? } 
end
```

But this will give me an error like:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `post?' for #

Is this the correct way to do it? or there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `user` presence can be validated using `if` option:

```
validates :user, presence: true, if: :post?
```